# Cannot Start Apache2 - httpd bound to port 80

Tags: apache2, httpd, ubuntu-22.04

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 22.04, on which I installed apache2 via `apt-get install`
After the installation I got the following error whenever I tried to start Apache2:

> (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80

After some investigation, I found that httpd was already bound to port 80 and preventing Apache2 starting. I hadn't realised that this version of Ubuntu Server came pre-installed with Nextcloud (via snap) which obviously already had a webserver to run!

Killing the process doesn't seem to work, as it just springs back up again before I can restart apache2.

There is no `/etc/httpd` directory and the `/etc/apache2/` path relates to my installation that can't start, so how do I find the config files of the mysterious apache server that is already running?

I would eventually want to have Nextcloud running on this system but my primary goal is to have a running webserver to serve pages locally on the network.

Thanks in advance

James

Comment: Try : ps -eaf | grep http      This may give you the path of the installed apache server. You can also try : lsof | grep 80

Comment: Thanks Ptit, this confirmed that the httpd instance was inside the Nextcloud snap container

Answer (score 0):

> I hadn't realised that this version of Ubuntu Server came pre-installed with Nextcloud

So presumably you would be happy to get rid of it.

Check the spelling (and capitalization) of the package name using `snap list`, then remove the package with `snap remove nextcloud` (or whatever name its using).

Comment: Great, thanks - that lets Apache2 start and bind successfully.  I have not used snap / containerised systems before - it seems strange to me that nextcloud includes it's own apache instance that conflicts with a traditional instance of apache as in this case?!